# How to delete an element from an array and printing the rest?

Tags: c, arrays

I want to print the array as it is after deleting the number 42 from the array. Here's the code which is running fine but I am not able to determine how to delete this one element and printing the rest.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {
        int i,a;
        int arr[]={1,2,42,88,99};
        a=sizeof(arr);
        for(i=0;i<=a;i++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
            if(arr[i]==42)
                break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    `
```

Comment: You can't modify arrays in C. Do you have to _delete_ it or can you just not print it?

Comment: You can't easily "delete" an element from an array. You need to shift all subsequent elements down one slot. It'd be much more efficient to simply "skip" that element in your loop which is printing the array.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered because it's based on incorrect assumptions: you cannot delete (or add) elements from/to an array at all. It's fixed in size.

Answer (score 4):

Before you code something you need to know what exactly you need and how to code it.

The following things should be fixed:

```
a=sizeof(arr);
```

To get the length of the array you need:

```
a=sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];
```

next you have this `for`:

```
for(i=0;i<=a;i++){}
```

here you need to check if `i < a` and not also to check if `i` becomes same as `a` like `i == a`, change it to:

```
or(i=0;i<a;i++){}
```

and here:

```
if(arr[i]==42)
    break;
```

You don't need to stop the loop, what you exactly need is to skip that number, this means you need `continue` here and not `break`:

```
if(arr[i]==42){
    continue;
}
```

and the last thing, move `printf("%d\n", arr[i]);` after that `if`.

Now putting all together you have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i,a;
    int arr[]={1,2,42,88,99};
    a=sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];

    for(i=0;i<a;i++){
        if(arr[i]==42){
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
88
99
```

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good eye :D

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
a = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int);
```

Then `i < a`, not `<=`

And last, you need `continue` instead of `break`.

And you need to put the if *before* the printf.

Comment: I use `#define ARRAY_LEN(x)   (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))`.

Comment: Better: `#define ARRAY_LEN(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))`

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I use a slightly shorter version `(sizeof(x) / sizeof *(x))`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to skip 42 with continue

```
 if(arr[i]==42)
     continue;
 }
 printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
```

Comment: It is still printing 42 after these changes.

Comment: Impossible. Post the whole new code ? I think you still have kept your first printf, i.e. you have now two printf in your loop. Get rid of the first printf.

Comment: Impossible? No. Inconceivable? Definitely.

Comment: One small error, thus the "42" got printed. Fixed it. Thanks @MadPhysicist

Answer (score 0):

writing a code here, which will delete given array elements. the code is :

```
    //delete elements
countDel=0;
for(i=0;i< n;i++)
{
    if(arr[i]==num)
    {
        countDel++;
        //shift all other elements up
        for(j=i;j< n;j++){
            arr[j]=arr[j+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,a;
    int arr[]={1,2,42,88,99};
    a=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++) 
        if(arr[i]!=42) printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```